# Stop user input from stdin in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, stdin, a86

I am quite new to assembly and trying to figure out reading input from stdin.
How do we terminate reading input after user presses enter ?

I am using a86 in dosbox.

```
jmp lo

readChar:
    mov ah, 01h ; we want to read 
    int 21h ; result in al
ret

lo:
    call readChar
    jnz lo
    int 20h ; exit
```

Comment: You compare the input with the ascii code of enter (13).

Comment: http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-a.html could be helpful